# Question about $y^\prime(x) = A y(x) + g(x) e^{ax}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Considering the differential equation

$$y^\prime(x) = A y(x) + g(x) e^{ax}$$

where $A \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ and $a \in \Bbb R$ is no eigenvalue of $A$, and $g(x)$ a polynomial vector, then there exists a particular solution

$$y_p(x) = h(x) e^{ax}$$

where $h(x)$ is a polynomial vector.

I tried some approaches, but I couldn't solve it.

differentiating $y_p$ I got $y_p'(x)=h'(x)e^{ax}+h(x)ae^{ax}$, inserting it into the equation yields

$$h'(x)e^{ax}+h(x)ae^{ax}= A h(x) e^{ax} + g(x) e^{ax}$$
$$e^{ax}(h'(x)+h(x)a)= e^{ax}(A h(x)  + g(x))$$
Thats how far I got. My problem now is that a is no eigenvalue.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the particular solution into both sides of the equality you wish to prove ? This question shows no effort, please edit it accordingly. What exactly are those “approaches” you tried but they didn't work ?

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq that was exactly my approach.

Comment: Is $*$ supposed to be $\times$?

Comment: @ThePointer no just multiplication

Comment: Did you try to write out $ah(x)+h'(x)=Ah(x)+g(x)$?

Comment: @WanyM Do you mean a$\left( \begin{array}{c} h_0 \\\ h_1x \end{array}\right)+\left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\\ h_1 \end{array}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{c} a_{11}h_0+a_{12}h_1x \\\ a_{21}h_0+a{22h_1x} \end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases to consider:

(a) $A$ is diagonalizable. In this case, decompose $h$ and $g$ in the basis of eigenvectors of $A$, and your last equation becomes
$$
h_i'(x)+ah_i(x)=\lambda_ih_i(x)+g_i(x)\qquad (i=1,2), \tag{1}
$$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. If $g_i(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}g_{i,k}x^k$, we can find a particular solution to $(1)$ in the form of a polynomial $h_i(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}h_{i,k}x^k$ by solving the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
(a-\lambda_i)h_{i,n} = g_{i,n} \\
nh_{i,n}+(a-\lambda_i)h_{i,n-1} = g_{i,n-1} \\
(n-1)h_{i,n-1}+(a-\lambda_i)h_{i,n-2} = g_{i,n-2} \\
\vdots \\
h_{i,1}+(a-\lambda_i)h_{i,0} = g_{i,0}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$

(b) $A$ is nondiagonalizable. In this case, there is a basis in which $A$ has the Jordan normal form
$$
P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1\\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}. \tag{3}
$$
In this basis, instead of Eq.$(1)$ we have
$$
\begin{cases}
h_1'(x)+ah_1(x)=\lambda h_1(x)+h_2(x)+g_1(x) \\
h_2'(x)+ah_2(x)=\lambda h_2(x)+g_2(x) 
\end{cases} \tag{4}
$$
If $g(x)$ is a polynomial, we can find a particular polynomial solution to the second equation of $(4)$ applying the same method used in case (a). Inserting the result in the first equation, we can again apply the same method to determine the coefficients of the polynomial $h_1(x)$ in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial $(h_2+g_1)(x)$.